# I can`t test my app which is registered on google play console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have a problem to test my app which is registered on google play console.

I registered it on google play console as the alpha and beta test version.

After a whole day, I can`t find my app on my app page of google play store.

Is this wrong to finding test app on google play store?

I don`t know how to test my app really, because it is the first app for me.
If anyone knows that,

Please help me.

I need to know how to test my app in details

Step by step....

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but the app submission process and Google's app management services.

Answer (score 0):

Apps that have been published through the Alpha or Beta but are not yet in Production don't appear in searches.

To install your app (e.g. com.your.app) you must first become a tester for it, then open https://play.google.com/apps/details?id=com.your.app on your Android device and click on the button to install it.

Answer (score 0):

When you release your app to alpha, you are given an opt-in link. Click that link, and/or give that link to any other testers. Once you've clicked that, go to Google Play Store and you should find your app under Menu -> My apps & games -> Library. There you can install it and it will appear in Menu -> My apps & games -> Installed for updates.